# Apêndice x Anexo

Tags: diferenças

Qual é a diferença entre "apêndice" e "anexo"?

Comment: Eu estou em duvida se respondo, até aonde sei apêndice é um órgão humano, agora fiquei curioso.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Se gerou essa dúvida, então talvez a pergunta faça mesmo sentido no site. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ambos se referem a adições que se fazem a um documento principal.

No entanto, apêndice é um documento que, apesar de não estar no documento principal, tem dados e referências ao mesmo.

Um anexo, por sua vez, é considerado qualquer documento separado do documento principal, mas que oferece informações adicionais sobre o tema tratado.

Exemplos:

Em trabalhos académicos, muitas vezes são recolhidas grandes quantidades de dados. Estes dados são usados para gerar gráficos. No entanto dado o volume dos mesmos, o autor pode decidir omiti-los do documento principal. O autor pode no entanto colocar os dados originais como apêndice e fazer uma menção para o leitor os consultar.

Ainda nos trabalhos académicos, por vezes é necessário acrescentar as fichas técnicas dos equipamentos usados. Essa fichas são colocados como anexo do documento principal dado que não são directamente relacionados com o documento mas oferecem mais informação/contexto sobre o tema.

Comment: Boa resposta. E a questão da autoria? Algumas vezes já ouvi argumentos de que há também distinções a respeito da autoria (mesmo autor, ou não, do documento principal e do apêndice/anexo).

Comment: Normalmente os apêndices são da autoria do autor do documento principal. Os anexos no entanto, como disse na resposta, como podem oferecer informação sobre o tema principal sem estarem directamente ligados ao documento principal, podem ser de autores diferentes. Um exemplo de anexo seria uma ficha informativa de um produto. A autoria e do fornecedor do produto, e no entanto esta anexado ao seu documento.

Answer (score 3):

### Apêndice

Um apêndice pode ser:

- apêndice (livro), conjunto de informações suplementares normalmente no fim de um livro ou outra publicação
- apêndice (biologia), extensão do corpo de um animal
- o apêndice vermiforme do intestino humano e de outros mamíferos
- apêndice articulado, as estruturas pares do corpo dos artrópodes
- apêndice xifóide, extremidade do osso esterno

Fonte: [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apêndice](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%AAndice)

### Anexo

A palavra *anexo* ou *apenso* se referencia é que vai ligado ou acompanhado de outro "documento" (ou cartas, ou relatórios e trabalhos de casa) geralmente, tanto documentos físico quanto virtuais, como é o caso do e-mail.

Geralmente são outros documentos ou fotos.

### A diferença de apêndice (livro) e Anexo

Acredito que a sua duvida se refira ao primeiro item citado (apêndice (livro)), conforme este [link](http://www.tudosobremonografia.com/2011/01/diferenca-entre-anexo-e-apendice.html)

1. **Anexo** - Documento ou texto *não* elaborado pelo autor
2. **Apêndice** - Documento ou texto elaborado pelo autor